# Binary search tree: min element

Tags: prolog

I tried to search for this but without luck; please let me know if the question has been answered!

Assuming I have a binary tree with key-value pairs of the form:

- `t/0`: the empty tree
- `t/4`: a tree node with `t(Key, Value, Left, Right)`

Now I want to get the first (min) element. The obvious (to me) implementation was:

```
min0(t(K,V,t,_), K, V) :- !.
min0(t(_,_,L,_), K, V) :- min0(L, K, V).
```

The implementation in SWI-Prolog's `library(assoc)` however is along the lines of:

```
min(t(K,V,L,_), Key, Val) :- min(L, K, V, Key, Val).
min(t,K,V,K,V).
min(t(E,K,V,_), _, _, Key, Val) :- min(L, K, V, Key, Val).
```

Other operations like `max` and `get` show the same difference in approach.

Why? What am I missing here? As far as I can see, my version is not creating choice points. But then again, I need a cut in the base case.

Comment: I'm not seeing it either, so I'm glad you asked. It'll be very interesting to find out the reason.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your version *does* create a choice-point when the clauses are considered for execution. `!/0` cuts the previously created choice point away. Your version does not allow indexing on the first argument but relies on a unification at a deeper place in the term. Did you already benchmark the two version on a large binary tree? Other than that, I find the SWI version more elegant because the two cases of tree terms which you mention naturally occur in it.

Comment: No, I did not benchmark it on large trees before asking... I assumed my solution is less efficient, I couldn't figure out why. If I understand you, the first clause of `min0` is _considered_ for execution, even though it does not show up in the trace, while `min`, having different first arguments, does not have this problem? Anyway, I see how the library solution is more elegant, and I will try to reuse this approach if I encounter a similar situation.

Comment: This is true, and moreover (and that is what I meant), even if the term is `t(K,V,` **t** `,_)`, your version creates a choice point because the *second* clause cannot be ruled out by first argument indexing. This is why you instinctively put a cut there.

Comment: In hindsight, the fact that I need a cut and clause order is important should have made it clear why my `min0` is not optimal. Unification is great if you know how to use it.

Comment: Yes, the SWI version is a true relation that can be used in all directions. It is quite common with Prolog programs that the most elegant version is also most efficient.